# How to remove record in EF many-to-many relations?

Tags: entity-framework

I am working on my tutorial project I am new to Entity Framework.

I have many two many relationship tables I am using code first approach.

[image]

Here is tables definition:

```
 class EmployeeDBContext : DbContext
{
    public EmployeeDBContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

//================================================My entities=================================================
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{  
    [Key]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

The course table filled with 3 subjects:History, Math, Physics.

I need to remove student that relate to some existing courses.

Any idea how can I implement it?

Comment: Once you obtain some `Course`, just remove its related Students and save normally. You don't need even touch the `Courses` collection (on Student side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that this way:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var student1 = ctx.Students.Find(1);
    if (student1 != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in student1.Courses.ToList())
            student1.Courses.Remove(item);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: what if I have multiple students related to one course?

Comment: @Michael So first you can grab that specific course and delete its related objects, like the code I posted.

Comment: what if I need to update many2many relationship table. Is is it good approach to delete and then add new records?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we want remove students related to Math and History Courses from the relationship.

```
 var relatedStudents = context.Students.Include(x=>x.Courses)
      .Where(s=>s.Courses.Any(c=>c.CourseName == "Math" && c.CourseName == "History"))
      .ToList();
 var math = context.Courses.First(x=>x.CourseName = "Math");
 var history = context.Courses.First(x=>x.CourseName = "History");
 foreach(Student s in relatedStudents)
 {
     s.Courses.Remove(math);
     s.Courses.Remove(history);
 }
 context.SaveChanges();
```